# Snakemake, numerous rules with different sets of wildcards

Tags: python, snakemake

I would like to write a series of rules, but some rules do not use the same wildcards as other rules. When I try this, Snakemake cannot determine the wildcards.

Suppose I have a workflow like this:

1. generate separate data files for 30 chromosomes
2. run a program called "algorithm1" with parameter "foo" on each of these 30 chromosomes
3. run a different program called "algorithm2" with parameter "bar" on each of these 30 chromosomes
4. Algorithm 1 and 2 are not related; I want algorithm 1 to run then afterwards algortihm2.

An illustrative workflow which you can run at home (changing `user`) looks like this:

```
rule all:
    input:
        [f'/home/user/snakemake_test_220905/algorithm2/parameter1_{alg2_param1}/littlefile{chrom}_analysis.txt' for chrom in range(0,10) for alg1_param1 in ['foo'] for alg2_param1 in ['bar']]

    
rule write_separate_vcf:
    input: 
        infile = '/home/user/snakemake_test_220905/big_file.vcf'
    output: 
        outfile = '/home/user/snakemake_test_220905/littlefile{chrom}.vcf'
    run:
        shell(
            f'echo "file{wildcards.chrom}" > {output.outfile}'
        )

rule algorithm_1:
    input: 
        infile = '/home/user/snakemake_test_220905/littlefile{chrom}.vcf'
    output:
        outfile = '/home/user/snakemake_test_220905/algorithm1/parameter1_{alg1_param1}/littlefile{chrom}_analysis.txt'
    run:
        shell(
            f'echo "parameter_{wildcards.alg1_param1}_{input.infile}" > {output.outfile}'
        )

rule algorithm_2:
    input: 
        infile = '/home/user/snakemake_test_220905/littlefile{chrom}.vcf',
        inile_flag = '/home/user/snakemake_test_220905/algorithm1/parameter1_{alg1_param1}/littlefile{chrom}_analysis.txt' # force dependency
    output:
        outfile = '/home/user/snakemake_test_220905/algorithm2/parameter1_{alg2_param1}/littlefile{chrom}_analysis.txt'
    run:
        shell(
            f'echo "parameter_{wildcards.alg2_param1}_{input.infile}" > {output.outfile}'
        )
```

(use `for i in {1..10}; do echo vcf$i >> big_file.vcf; done` to create the big_file.vcf)

This of course fails, the returned error is:

```
WildcardError in line 29 of /home/user/snakemake_test_220905/Snakefile:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'alg1_param1'
```

I would like all the files to be written at once, but can't figure out an elegant way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The output of rule `algorithm_2` should contain `{alg1_param1}` otherwise different values of `{alg1_param1}` would lead to the same output. This is not a limitation of snakemake, if it was allowed you would have files overwriting each other. For example use:

```
outfile = 'algorithm2/{alg1_param1}/parameter1_{alg2_param1}/littlefile{chrom}_analysis.txt'
```

Output of rule `all` should change accordingly.

Comment: Oh, but suppose I run everything and it all goes fine. If I then want to run again but with a different alg1_param1, then it will redo everything with algorithm 2 even though the parameters for algorithm 2 are the same.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your purpose here... If you change `{alg1_param1}` and, as a consequence, run rule `algorithm_1` again, then also rule `algorithm_2` has to run again because the input of `algorithm_2` has changed. In a sense, `{alg1_param1}` is a parameter of `algorithm_2` as well even if it doesn't take it explicitly.